# Viber through Wine, crash on calling with unexpected error

Tags: 12.04, wine, 32-bit, opengl, viber

12.04 Precise 32 bit system, currently have Viber running under Wine due to system architecture.

Gotten it to install and messaging works as a charm although upon firing a call it quits
with an unexpected error every time! possibly due to libraries problems.

windows error reports suggests the ever occurring I/O access memory problems and some OpenGL libraries possibly with concern to pop-up GUI window on click.

Any body gotten a hand on this

regards

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000004 in 32-bit code (0x007a1280).
Register dump:
 CS:0073 SS:007b DS:007b ES:007b FS:0033 GS:003b
 EIP:007a1280 ESP:0033c928 EBP:0033ca44 EFLAGS:00210212(  R- --  I   -A- - )
 EAX:076e2cd8 EBX:00000000 ECX:00000000 EDX:00000000
 ESI:04879510 EDI:076e2cd8
Stack dump:
0x0033c928:  009555e3 00000000 04879510 00000001
0x0033c938:  04879510 009531db 00955795 00000000
0x0033c948:  00916740 04879348 6301883c 082ca608
0x0033c958:  082ca600 03a84350 0000025b 000001ab
0x0033c968:  00000000 00000000 0000025a 000001aa
0x0033c978:  008e63ec 00a5644c 00000000 0033ca74
Backtrace:
=>0 0x007a1280 ?shareGroup@QOpenGLContext@@QBEPAVQOpenGLContextGroup@@XZ() in qt5gui (0x0033ca44)
  1 0x008e664e in qt5gui (+0x18664d) (0x039a9998)
  2 0x039a9970 (0x652e3a94)
  3 0x6503ec90 in qt5widgets (+0x3ec8f) (0x65260ac0)
  4 0xe98b5502 (0x042444f6)
0x007a1280 ?shareGroup@QOpenGLContext@@QBEPAVQOpenGLContextGroup@@XZ in qt5gui: movl    0x4(%ecx),%eax
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (215 modules)
PE    340000-  3ff000   Deferred        libglesv2
PE    400000-  4e7000   Deferred        viber
PE    600000-  61a000   Deferred        qfacebook
PE    620000-  727000   Deferred        icuuc51
PE    730000-  75d000   Deferred        libexif
PE    760000-  a7c000   Export          qt5gui
PE    a80000- 1ac1000   Deferred        qt5webkit
PE   1ad0000- 1cf5000   Deferred        qt5quick
PE   1d00000- 1d0f000   Deferred        libegl
PE   1d10000- 1d40000   Deferred        qt5webkitwidgets
PE   1d40000- 1d83000   Deferred        qt5printsupport
PE   1d90000- 1f88000   Deferred        qt5declarative
PE   1f90000- 20ad000   Deferred        qt5script
PE   2360000- 2369000   Deferred        qgif
PE   2370000- 2379000   Deferred        qico
PE   23a0000- 23a8000   Deferred        qsvg
PE   2710000- 27ec000   Deferred        qwindows
PE   27f0000- 2826000   Deferred        qjpeg
PE   2830000- 2869000   Deferred        qmng
PE   2870000- 28a5000   Deferred        qt5svg
PE   28b0000- 28b8000   Deferred        qtga
PE   28c0000- 2910000   Deferred        qtiff
PE   2910000- 2918000   Deferred        qwbmp
PE   3420000- 34bf000   Deferred        qsqlite
PE   43e0000- 45e7000   Deferred        d3dcompiler_43
PE   6630000- 663a000   Deferred        qsvgicon
PE  10000000-129a0000   Deferred        libviber
PE  4a900000-4aa58000   Deferred        icuin51
PE  4ad00000-4c24c000   Deferred        icudt51
PE  61000000-6126c000   Deferred        qt5xmlpatterns
PE  62000000-62029000   Deferred        qt5sql
PE  63000000-63040000   Deferred        qt5opengl
PE  64000000-641dc000   Deferred        qt5network
PE  65000000-65431000   Export          qt5widgets
PE  66000000-6626c000   Deferred        qt5qml
PE  67000000-673f1000   Deferred        qt5core
PE  78050000-780b9000   Deferred        msvcp100
PE  78aa0000-78b5f000   Deferred        msvcr100
ELF 7b800000-7ba15000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba15000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bad4000-7baff000   Deferred        msvfw32<elf>
  \-PE  7bae0000-7baff000   \               msvfw32
ELF 7baff000-7bb42000   Deferred        dsound<elf>
  \-PE  7bb10000-7bb42000   \               dsound
ELF 7bb42000-7bc00000   Deferred        quartz<elf>
  \-PE  7bb50000-7bc00000   \               quartz
ELF 7bc00000-7bcc3000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcc3000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bcc7000-7bceb000   Deferred        devenum<elf>
  \-PE  7bcd0000-7bceb000   \               devenum
ELF 7bceb000-7bd16000   Deferred        libvorbis.so.0
ELF 7bd16000-7be8e000   Deferred        libvorbisenc.so.2
ELF 7be8e000-7bf00000   Deferred        libsndfile.so.1
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7bf0d000-7bf5b000   Deferred        libflac.so.8
ELF 7bf5b000-7bfc0000   Deferred        libpulsecommon-1.1.so
ELF 7bfc0000-7c00e000   Deferred        libpulse.so.0
ELF 7c00e000-7c100000   Deferred        libasound.so.2
ELF 7c404000-7c41d000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7c410000-7c41d000   \               msacm32
ELF 7c42e000-7c436000   Deferred        libogg.so.0
ELF 7c436000-7c43d000   Deferred        libasyncns.so.0
ELF 7c44e000-7c455000   Deferred        libasound_module_pcm_pulse.so
ELF 7c455000-7c481000   Deferred        winealsa<elf>
  \-PE  7c460000-7c481000   \               winealsa
ELF 7c481000-7c4a4000   Deferred        mmdevapi<elf>
  \-PE  7c490000-7c4a4000   \               mmdevapi
ELF 7c4f5000-7c4fc000   Deferred        libnss_dns.so.2
ELF 7c4fc000-7c500000   Deferred        libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
ELF 7c604000-7c60e000   Deferred        libwrap.so.0
ELF 7c60e000-7c617000   Deferred        libjson.so.0
ELF 7c61a000-7c658000   Deferred        rsaenh<elf>
  \-PE  7c620000-7c658000   \               rsaenh
ELF 7c759000-7c78d000   Deferred        libtxc_dxtn.so
ELF 7c78d000-7c798000   Deferred        libpciaccess.so.0
ELF 7c798000-7c7b6000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7c89b000-7c8be000   Deferred        libdrm_intel.so.1
ELF 7c8be000-7cc80000   Deferred        libdricore9.1.7.so.1
ELF 7cc80000-7cd5b000   Deferred        i965_dri.so
ELF 7cd5b000-7cd73000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF 7cd73000-7ce00000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7cd90000-7ce00000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7cf03000-7cf10000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF 7cf10000-7cf15000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF 7cf15000-7cf18000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF 7cf18000-7cf2e000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF 7cf2e000-7cf88000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF 7d296000-7d2b4000   Deferred        wintab32<elf>
  \-PE  7d2a0000-7d2b4000   \               wintab32
ELF 7d2b4000-7d2c8000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d2c0000-7d2c8000   \               psapi
ELF 7d2c8000-7d326000   Deferred        dbghelp<elf>
  \-PE  7d2d0000-7d326000   \               dbghelp
ELF 7d427000-7d430000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7d430000-7d434000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7d434000-7d47e000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7d47e000-7d487000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 7d487000-7d4af000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 7d4af000-7d57e000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 7d57e000-7d590000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 7d590000-7d59e000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 7d59e000-7d5dc000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 7d5dc000-7d62f000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 7d630000-7d634000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF 7d634000-7d647000   Deferred        gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
ELF 7d647000-7d67b000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7d650000-7d67b000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7d67d000-7d693000   Deferred        midimap<elf>
  \-PE  7d680000-7d693000   \               midimap
ELF 7d693000-7d699000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7d699000-7d6a4000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7d6a5000-7d6ba000   Deferred        avicap32<elf>
  \-PE  7d6b0000-7d6ba000   \               avicap32
ELF 7d726000-7d750000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7d750000-7d784000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7d784000-7d795000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7d795000-7d799000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7d799000-7d7a2000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7d7a2000-7d7ac000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7d7ac000-7d7b2000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7d7b2000-7d7b6000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7d7b6000-7d7d8000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7d7c0000-7d7d8000   \               imm32
ELF 7d7d8000-7d7df000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7d7df000-7d7e3000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7d7e3000-7d804000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7d804000-7d80a000   Deferred        libuuid.so.1
ELF 7d80a000-7d824000   Deferred        libice.so.6
ELF 7d824000-7d958000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7d958000-7d96a000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7d96a000-7d973000   Deferred        libsm.so.6
ELF 7d973000-7da06000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7d980000-7da06000   \               winex11
ELF 7da06000-7daa0000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7dab8000-7dad3000   Deferred        msdmo<elf>
  \-PE  7dac0000-7dad3000   \               msdmo
ELF 7dad3000-7dbc5000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7daf0000-7dbc5000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7dbc5000-7dca4000   Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE  7dbd0000-7dca4000   \               comdlg32
ELF 7dca4000-7dcde000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  7dcb0000-7dcde000   \               winspool
ELF 7dcde000-7dd06000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7dce0000-7dd06000   \               msacm32
ELF 7dd06000-7ddb3000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7dd10000-7ddb3000   \               winmm
ELF 7ddb3000-7dde4000   Deferred        libcrypt.so.1
ELF 7dde4000-7de89000   Deferred        libsqlite3.so.0
ELF 7de89000-7ded0000   Deferred        libhx509.so.5
ELF 7ded0000-7def9000   Deferred        libwind.so.0
ELF 7def9000-7df0b000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7df0b000-7df21000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7df21000-7dfc6000   Deferred        libasn1.so.8
ELF 7dfc6000-7e049000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.26
ELF 7e049000-7e0cf000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.11
ELF 7e0f1000-7e100000   Deferred        libheimbase.so.1
ELF 7e100000-7e112000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.3
ELF 7e112000-7e128000   Deferred        libroken.so.18
ELF 7e128000-7e15d000   Deferred        libhcrypto.so.4
ELF 7e15d000-7e165000   Deferred        libheimntlm.so.0
ELF 7e165000-7e229000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.26
ELF 7e229000-7e266000   Deferred        libgssapi.so.3
ELF 7e266000-7e282000   Deferred        libsasl2.so.2
ELF 7e282000-7e2d4000   Deferred        libldap_r-2.4.so.2
ELF 7e2d4000-7e330000   Deferred        wldap32<elf>
  \-PE  7e2e0000-7e330000   \               wldap32
ELF 7e330000-7e3e8000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE  7e340000-7e3e8000   \               crypt32
ELF 7e3e8000-7e40a000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e3f0000-7e40a000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7e40a000-7e435000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e410000-7e435000   \               netapi32
ELF 7e435000-7e44d000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7e44e000-7e465000   Deferred        wtsapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e450000-7e465000   \               wtsapi32
ELF 7e465000-7e484000   Deferred        dnsapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e470000-7e484000   \               dnsapi
ELF 7e484000-7e57c000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e490000-7e57c000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e57c000-7e5e6000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e590000-7e5e6000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e5e6000-7e7f7000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e5f0000-7e7f7000   \               shell32
ELF 7e7f7000-7e829000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e800000-7e829000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7e829000-7e95d000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  7e840000-7e95d000   \               wined3d
ELF 7e95d000-7e996000   Deferred        d3d9<elf>
  \-PE  7e960000-7e996000   \               d3d9
ELF 7e996000-7ea0b000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e9a0000-7ea0b000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7ea0b000-7eb13000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7ea20000-7eb13000   \               ole32
ELF 7eb13000-7eb2c000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eb20000-7eb2c000   \               version
ELF 7eb2c000-7eb8c000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb40000-7eb8c000   \               advapi32
ELF 7eb8c000-7ec49000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7eba0000-7ec49000   \               gdi32
ELF 7ec49000-7ed89000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7ec60000-7ed89000   \               user32
ELF 7ed89000-7ed96000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ed96000-7eda2000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7eda2000-7edbc000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7efbc000-7efe8000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efea000-7eff9000   Deferred        liblber-2.4.so.2
ELF b73e0000-b73e5000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF b73e5000-b73ee000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF b73ef000-b73f4000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF b73f4000-b759e000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF b759f000-b75ba000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF b75ba000-b75bf000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF b75d2000-b7714000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF b7716000-b7738000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF b7738000-b7739000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    0000001f    0
    0000001e    0
    00000015    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001c    0
    00000019    0
    00000014    0
    00000013    0
0000001a plugplay.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001d    0
    0000001b    0
00000021 explorer.exe
    00000022    0
00000023 (D) C:\users\steliyan\Local Settings\Application Data\Viber\Viber.exe
    00000047    0
    00000043    0
    00000042    0
    00000041    0
    00000040    0
    0000003f   15
    0000003e   15
    0000003d    0
    0000003c    0
    0000003b    0
    00000039    0
    00000038    2
    00000037    0
    00000036    0
    00000035    0
    00000034    0
    00000030    0
    0000002f    0
    0000002d    0
    0000002c    0
    0000002b    0
    0000002a    0
    00000029    0
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    00000026    0
    00000024    0 <==
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.4
    Platform: i386
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 3.8.0-44-generic
```

Comment: Use [Viber for Linux](http://www.viber.com/en/products/linux) Is there a reason you use it through Wine?

Comment: yes I have tried, but I am not running 64bit system I can't make it do it, don't know the function

Comment: Mitch, how did you wrap the whole text around, I had to select it one by one?

Comment: Select the text then press Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem on  Mint 17.1 + Viber + AceStream fixed by:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libace_plugin.so /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/
```